# How can we create T[] array in a method of a GenericClass<T>?

Tags: java, generics

The below method is created in a Generic Class. I am quite new to Java so any pointers would be a great help.

```
public class LinkedList<T>{

public T[] toArray(){
        T[] array = (T[]) new Object[size];
        Node<T> curr = first;
        int index = 0;
        while (curr != null){
            array[index++] = curr.value;
            curr = curr.next;
        }
        return array;
    }
```

}

When I use this I get ClassCastException when I try to access the Main method like below.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
LinkedList<Integer> list = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    var a = list.toArray();
    System.out.println(a.toString());
}
```

Below is the exception I am getting when executing the above code.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class
> [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to class [Ljava.lang.Integer;
> ([Ljava.lang.Object; and [Ljava.lang.Integer; are in module java.base
> of loader 'bootstrap')    at com.company.Main.main(Main.java:49)

Comment: I think you need T[] a = list.toArray() instead of var? With T being whatever type of object you are putting into your array.

Comment: Show the stacktrace and the line that actually triggers it

Comment: There is a reason why [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html) only provides `Object[] toArray()` and `T[] toArray(T[] a)` and no `T[] toArray()`. Reason is that it is not possible.

Comment: As an alternative you could consider `Stream.iterate(first, Objects::notNull, n->n.next).map(n -> n.value).toArray()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the pointer [Turing85](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4216641/turing85) to [List](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html) Java docs.
I got my code working.

```
public class LinkedList<T>{
public T[] toArray(T[] type){ //Made a change here from the Original code
        Node<T> curr = first;
        int index = 0;
        while (curr != null){
            type[index++] = curr.value;
            curr = curr.next;
        }
        return (T[]) type;
    }
}
```

Main Method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    LinkedList<Integer> list = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    var a = list.toArray(new Integer[list.getSize()]); //Made a change here
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
}
```